# AngularJS: Access a factory or service from 3rd party library

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, dependency-injection

Here is my problem: I am building an application mostly angular-based, but also using some non-angular code. I have organized my code in modules, including some factories. In particular I have a factory dedicated to logging, which is injected in various modules.

What if I want to access this logging factory from non-angular-packaged code, where I can't use the brilliant dependency-injection mechanism from angular?

```
/* Angular app */
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('logger', function(){
   return {
       infos : [],
       logInfo : function(msg) { this.infos.push(msg); }
   };
});

app.controller('MyCtrl',['logger', function(logger){
   ...
   logger.logInfo("Here I can use the dependency-injected logger");
   ...
}]);

/* Rest of the app */

someLib.someMethod(function(){
   ...
   // var logger = angular.getFactory('logger') ?
   logger.logInfo("Gee, how do I access my logger from here?");
   ...
});
```

I did find a way around this problem, but I don't find it very satisfying, nor safe:

```
// Declare the logger globally
var logger = {
  infos : [],
  logInfo : function(msg) { this.infos.push(msg); }
};

// Still package it into a factory (although it's kinda pointless now)
app.factory('logger', function(){
  return logger;
});

/* Rest of the app */
someLib.someMethod(function(){
  ...
  logger.logInfo("Now logger is global, so I can access it from anywhere!");
  ...
});
```

So... Is there a way to inject dependencies in non-angular parts of the code?

Comment: Specifically for a logger (i.e. something that does not interact with Angular's digest cycle) I would NOT object to your solution. For completeness, and in addition to dfsq's answer, another way would be to inject the wanted Angular service into a `run` block and place it in a global context through this run block, i.e. `app.run(function(myService) { window.myService = myService; })`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would do it is to assign current application injector to the application module property so it would be easy to access it later. It's convenient to do it in the run block:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.run(function($injector) {
    app.$injector = $injector;
});
```

Now, later when you need to get some service from non-Angular code you can do this:

```
var logger = app.$injector.get('logger');
```

or

```
var logger = angular.module('myApp').$injector.get('logger');
```

So now you can use it:

```
someLib.someMethod(function() {
    var logger = angular.module('myApp').$injector.get('logger');
    logger.logInfo("Now logger is global, so I can access it from anywhere!");
});
```